# sd card - cannot mount / format / partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card

I have two sd cards of the same type: SanDisk Ultra UHS-I A1 32GB
One is brand new the other is already used.

Both cards show the same symptoms on my ArchLinux laptop (MacBook Pro 2013, system is up to date):

- They show up as /dev/mmcblk0 without any partition like /dev/mmcblk0p1.
- Therefore I cannot mount or format it
- When I use fdisk to create partitions I don't get any errors, fdisk claims it has written the new partition table successfully. But after that there is still only /dev/mmcblk0. When I run fdisk again it shows no partitions but 29.7GB of unpartitioned space

Since one card is brand new and the other is used by a Raspberry PI without problems I guess its a problem with my system and not with the cards.
I have some other 8GB sd cards from a different manufacture which are working fine with the same laptop.

`dmesg` shows

```
[ 1972.817757] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 5048
[ 1972.818449] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD32G 29.7 GiB 
[ 1982.874326] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 1982.874343] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[ 1982.874385] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x000010c8 | Version:  0x00001502
[ 1982.874429] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
[ 1982.874440] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
[ 1982.874449] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0000 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
[ 1982.874458] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[ 1982.874467] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[ 1982.874476] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[ 1982.874484] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff008b | Sig enab: 0x03ff008b
[ 1982.874492] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[ 1982.874500] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
[ 1982.874508] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x00000000
[ 1982.874515] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
[ 1982.874523] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
[ 1982.874528] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000804b
[ 1982.874537] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x0000000104fe3204
[ 1982.874541] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[ 1982.874616] mmc0: Unexpected interrupt 0x04000000.
[ 1982.874623] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[ 1982.874630] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001502
[ 1982.874637] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
[ 1982.874645] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
[ 1982.874654] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0001 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
[ 1982.874663] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[ 1982.874671] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[ 1982.874678] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[ 1982.874687] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff008b | Sig enab: 0x03ff008b
[ 1982.874695] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[ 1982.874704] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
[ 1982.874712] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000c1a | Max curr: 0x00000000
[ 1982.874720] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
[ 1982.874728] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
[ 1982.874734] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
[ 1982.874744] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x0000000104fe3204
[ 1982.874748] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

**edit**
After a lot of googleing I found that after the following code I am able to create partitions, format and mount them.

```
rmmod sdhci sdhci_pci sdhci_acpi
modprobe sdhci debug_quirks2="0x04"
modprobe sdhci_pci sdhci_acpi
```

Anyway when I copy some files to it and try to umount the partition the `umount` command gets stuck and never finishes. When I eject the sd card and mount it again no files are placed there.

Comment: How old is your "ArchLinux laptop"? Or, better, [edit] your question and post hardware specifications.

Comment: This sounds like a kernel (driver) bug/regression, if the reader and the cards are not broken (e.g. works under Windows).

Comment: @ChanganAuto It's a MacBook Pro 2013 with an up-to-date ArchLinux installed

Comment: I found this issue with the same dmesg message but the suggested workaround does not help https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org&q=subject:%22Bug%23830303%5C%3A+mmc0%5C%3A+Unexpected+interrupt+0x04000000.%22&o=newest&f=1