# Create multiple sd card partitions with MS-DOS format under MacOS

Tags: macos, partitioning, sd-card

I want to have 3 partitions on my sd card.
The Disk Utility does not give me this option when I select *MS-DOS (FAT32)* als format. The +/- buttons are greyed out. Only when I select *APFS* or *MacOS Extended* these buttons become active. But I need MS-DOS FAT32 format.

This is a super easy task using linux but I cannot find any way to do it using MacOS 10.14.6

Using gParted Live is not an option due to a bug in the linux kernel which causes the sd card reader not to work with my specific sd card [sd card - cannot mount / format / partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1772524/sd-card-cannot-mount-format-partition)

Comment: GParted Live... I hope someone can give you a better answer for disk utilities

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is not an option due to a bug in the linux kernel which causes the sd card reader not to work with my specific sd card  https://superuser.com/questions/1772524/sd-card-cannot-mount-format-partition

Comment: Maybe try with command-line utilities on macOS. They could be more flexible.

Comment: If the built-in card reader is having issues, then perhaps a USB-SD_card reader is the simplest solution that can restore all software choices, such as GParted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try virtualization. Use your preferred Hypervisor like VirtualBox or VMWare Player, create a new VM with about 4GB RAM, no virtual disks and removing every unecessary hardware like network, sound, and so on, later add a virtual disk from a physical device to the guest. There are different tutorials for using with VMWare or VBox regarding this matter, you just need to search for "add physical disk to VM" and you're good to go.

All the hard work will be done on the VM, later you just have to shutdown the VM and safely remove the card. Later put it back on and see if it worked. I used this trick to make advanced formatting unsupported by the device I am using. You can use any live disk partitioning ISO like GParted, PartedMagic, Minitool, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That actually sounds super complicated for such a simple task. How can this be that it's not supported natively  by Mac?

Comment: You can try a hacky method using the command line but I'm not familliar to MacOS tools. If there are tools like parted or fdisk on MacOS, you can always refer to their "help" options to know what commands you must run to execute what you need. Generally the help is open by appending --help after the command. `parted --help` or `fdisk --help`.

Edit: You might need to run those commands with admin elevation. `sudo` maybe?